# Find the index of an array of objects with just the value of the object's key using Node

Tags: arrays, node.js, underscore.js

I'm using Node's underscore module.

Lets say I have an array of objects;

```
var years =
[{year:"2000"},
{year:"2001"},
{year:"2002"}];
```

and I want to find the index of 2000 (0)

I don't think this is working. Is there another way in this module? or just javascript?

_.indexOf(years, 2000);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var index = _.findIndex(years, {year: "2000"});
```

would be the easiest option.